# Where does a Web service's Database typically sit?

Tags: database, web-services, database-connection, hosting, database-security

I am learning back-end development by developing a C# Web Service that interacts with a database. I am not sure, however, where the database is supposed to be kept. Is it supposed to be in the same location as where the web service will be hosted?

Comment: Ideally, the database is in more than one location for redundancy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[1]Yes,Usually Hosting provider will provide you database with any of your chosen plan like Shared Hosting/VPS Hosting/Dedicated Server.So you should keep your database in hosted environment.

[2]Take backup and keep a copy of it with your local system by FTP transfer.